# Windows sound control

Tags: linux, windows, audio

First of all, I know this is probably wrong place to post this, but I went through the list of servers and didn't find anything suitable.

Now to the question:

Until recently I have been a user of Linux (Ubuntu), but for many reasons I had to switch back to Windows. Few months ago, I have damaged my jack connector (laptop) and since then the sound does not work how it should.

Behavior on Linux:
Sound from internal speakers works fine. When I connect headphones (or anything into the jack) the sound is coming out both from internal speakers and the connected device. I have found workaround with alsamixer. In alsamixer I set Master volume to 100%, Speaker to 0 and headphones to desired level. It was annoying workaround (if you adjust volume by fn+key it reset it self and you need to set it up again...) but it worked.

Behavior on Windows:
Sound is coming from internal speakers fine, but when I connect anything to jack, it keeps coming from the internal speakers and nothing from the connected device. This basically means that I cannot use sound anyhow else than out loud which is obviously very limiting.

My question is: Is there any tool for windows such as alsamixer for linux that would allow me to get the sound out of connected device and at the same time mute the internal speaker?

Once again, I am very sorry about posting it here, and please feel free to move it anywhere it should belong.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Which laptop u are using?

Comment: Trust me, there is basically no way to reproduce the problem. This isn't any simple problem that could be solved by changing some settings in output or something like that... The problem is, as I said, that I have damaged the HW itself, basically almost destroyed the jack for input. So the contacts and stuff are messed up, BUT in linux there was a way to do a workaround to make it work. While in windows it looks like it just doesnt detect the jack at all. That's why I am asking if someone knows about some low-level controller. The laptop is Acer Aspire 4750G

Comment: First i would check if all your drivers are correctly installed just like ShivoHam said.
I have an solution if that does not work. But it will cost money.
And i only would do it if i really cant find any solution.

I would buy an USB To 3.5mm Jack Audio Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

-Open the Control Panel the click on RealTek HD Audio Manager then in the window that opens select Speakers.

-In the right hand column under digital or analog, depending on your settings, you’ll see your mic and headphone inputs represented by small circles.

-If nothing is plugged in then they should both be greyed out and unavailable, plug in your headphones if they are not already plugged in.

-The headphone circles should now be accessable, by that I mean not greyed out.
Right click and select “Connector Retasking” You’ll get a dialogue box pop up that says “The current connected device is”, Select “Headphones”.

-You will also see “Enable auto pop up dialog when device has been plugged in” check the box next to it and click OK.

-Your speakers should now cut out when your headphones are plugged in and you will get a dialogue box allowing you to change the setting should you wish.

hope it helps you :D.

source: http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/why-does-sound-come-from-internal-speakers-even-when-i-plug-in-headphones/

Comment: You just posted a link?

Comment: @RahulRDhobi Yes, but Thealon explained the inside of link here.

Answer (score 0):

http://xbmc.org/

try this tool.
If your hardware,drivers work fine and problem with OS.
It has good UI and may it can help you to resolve this issue.
Its an open source.work with windows/linux/mac etc.
may be it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may find solution in this discussion http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/why-does-sound-come-from-internal-speakers-even-when-i-plug-in-headphones/